# Microsoft Edge thinks it is default

Tags: microsoft-edge

Chrome is set as the default browser. Links in emails in Windows Live mail 2012 and Word 2010 open in Microsoft Edge anyway. The old Outlook Express had a settings portion where you could tell it which text editor and Browser and such but Windows Live doesn't have that (that I can find)

I understand Microsoft Edge is the new default browser for Windows 10 but I don't see a way to tell it directly to not be the default browser. I have set Chrome as the default in the Chrome settings and all but Microsoft programs seem to respect that.

How do I make it so Microsoft Edge is not the browser that opens when links in Windows Live mail and Word are clicked?

Comment: Please go in to detail explaining what steps you did to set Chrome as the default browser.

Comment: Are the "Links in emails" opened from within Google Chrome?

Comment: What mail client are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In the Windows 10 "Settings>System>Default apps" there is a place for selecting a default browser and it was indeed set to Edge. I changed it to Chrome and that took care of it.